# rsync replicate existing rsync server data

Tags: rsync

I have a master backup system that rsync's with windows servers and does incremental backups with the --link-dest flag. Works great. Each day it looks at the previous day and only backs up what changes with hard links.

I have spun up another server that on a weekly basis I want to replicate off these backups and then take offline. My first attempt at just doing a basic rsync yielded a full array as instead of copying all the links it sync'd the files in each directory in their full size each and every time.

Right now I have:

```
rsync -acvlPE --rsync-path="sudo rsync" <user>@<host>:/backupdir /<localdir>
```

This seemed to work fine on the first run through. It pretty well duplicated what was on the orginating server.

THe issue came when I ran the command again the next day. It did a full sync all over again, not just sync'ing what changed in the source.

Any thoughts on how to handle this better?

Comment: have you tried to use Windows deduplication? sometimes it is enabled and you may not notice it

Comment: this is a RHEL linux server backing up windows servers running cygwin rsync

Comment: this happens when questions don't follow [ask] ;)